# implementing memmove without copying the source data

Tags: c, memmove

I need to implement myself the standard  c function memmove.

```
void *memmove(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)
```

Can I avoid copying the source (pointed by str2) into a temporary buffer before doing the actual copy ?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple question, quick answer: Yes. -- It helps to get a good answer if you elaborate on your problem, show what you have so far, and what you think.

Comment: @thebusybee it isn't that simple.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala But sure, the question is "Can I ...", and that is a simple question that can be answered by yes or no. ;-) And even if we look into the _real_ issue behind the question, I feel that it helps the OP more if s/he thinks some minutes on the task.

Comment: And then reach the wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of [`memmove`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.2p2) says that

> Copying takes place **as if** the n characters from the object pointed to by s2 are first copied into a temporary array of n characters that does not overlap the objects pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n characters from the temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by s1.

Now the "as if" part tells that this is just used to explain the observable behaviour, and not that it is how an implementation actually has to do it.

But then comes the fun fact: it is actually **not possible** to implement `memmove` in portable standard C without copying the entire source into a temporary buffer in most cases (you could avoid doing a copy altogether if `src == dest`).

If you do character-by-character copy, you could check which pointer comes first in memory, i.e. if `target > source` it means that you would need to copy in reverse, i.e. starting from `n - 1` and copying backwards.

The caveat is that using `target > source` is strictly conforming **only** if both pointers point to members of the same array. This isn't just theoretical - x86 real mode segmented memory models for example can make pointer comparison difficult.

With the caveat in mind, you could just cast both to `uintptr_t` for the comparison and hope for the best (and fear for the worst). I believe converting to `uintptr_t` wouldn't work on x86 real mode (i.e. the "640 kilobytes should be enough for anyone" mode), but who'd want to program for it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code can help you:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

typedef uint32_t size_t;

void * memmove(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len){
    uint8_t *dp = (uint8_t *)dst;
    const uint8_t *sp = (const uint8_t *)src;
    
    if(sp < dp && sp + len > dp){
        sp += len;
        dp += len;
        while(len-- > 0){
            *--dp = *--sp;
        }
    }else{
        while(len-- > 0){
            *dp++ = *sp++;
        }
    }
    
    return dst;
}
```